# How to pre-load data from related field in sqlalchemy + pydantic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I have such tables

```
class Address(Base):
    event_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(
        sa.Integer,
        sa.ForeignKey('events.id'),
        nullable=False
    )
    event = relationship(
        'Event',
        back_populates='address',
        uselist=False
    )
```

```
class Event(Base):
    address = relationship(
        'Address',
        uselist=False,
        back_populates='event',
    )
```

And I create event like event = Event(**data), session.add(event), session.commit()
So when I try to `EventSchema.from_orm(event_instance)`
then I got error, that `value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)`
Here is my EventSchema:

```
class AddressSchema(BaseModel):
    country: str
    city: str
    street: str
    build: str


class EventSchema(BaseModel):
    address: Optional[AddressSchema] = Field(...)
```

So, how I can pre-load data, to avoid this error?
I`d like to get such response:

```
{"id": 1, "address": {"country": "foocountry", "street": "foostreet"}
```

Comment: You still have to define `class Config` with `from_orm = True` on your models for pydantic to use orm loading: https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an `orm_mode = True` for AdressSchema

Comment: Just note that while fixing your issue, this doesn't actually **preload** `event_instance.address`, but rather, it is fetched once Pydantic accesses the field in the `from_orm` method. There are [several ways actually load both tables in one database roundtrip in SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html), for instance by adding an option to your query: `select(Event).options(joinedload(Event.address))`

Comment: Okay, so maybe I used wrong phrase to describe my problem, I just didn`t know that when you use fied as schema in pydantic model you have to add orm_mode to both models

Answer (score 0):

Your `Address` model doesn't have fields like country, city etc. Update your models and schema:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.orm as so


class Event(Base):
    address_id: so.Mapped[int] = so.mapped_column(
        sa.ForeignKey("address.id", ondelete="SET NULL"), nullable=True
    )
    address: so.Mapped[Address] = so.relationship(
        back_populates='event', lazy="selectin"
    )
```

```py
class EventSchema(BaseModel):
    address: Optional[AddressSchema] = None

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```